# Is Arduino able to update only part of firmware?

Tags: arduino, firmware, stm32f4discovery

I'm building a new project, and need to choose an MCU board.

What I'm trying is firmware's partial update. I will appoint part of firmware(like functions) on specific flash sector, and update only the sector so I don't need to erase&write the whole flash.

On my previous project, [STM32F4DISCOVERY](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html) worked really fine but I wonder is Arduino could be an option.

1. Is it possible to set an memory address for firmware(i.e. funcA->0x0030, funcB->0x0090)
2. Is there a way to jump flash cursor(execute the code on specific memory address)
3. Can Arduino dynamically erase/write on flash memory itself?

Comment: yes you can write into flash. on ARM Arduinos and modern AVR Arduinos directly. on classic AVR the Optiboot bootloader has a function for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boards.txt file holds a reference to the Linker Script where memory regions are configured including starting address and length of flash and RAM.

[FlashAsEEPROM](https://github.com/cmaglie/FlashStorage) is a library used to write/read the flash memory where EEPROM is not available.